# Azure TableQuery With Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Is there a way to query Azure for PartitionKeys that match a certain regular expression instead of just equality?

For example:

My Azure Storage Table PartitionKeys: CA94568, CA92122, CA92092, WA98005

Sample Query #1:

```
tableQuery = new TableQuery<Entry>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(PartitionKey, QueryComparisons.Equal??,  "CA.*"));
```

Query Results #1: "CA94568, CA92122, CA92092"

Sample Query #2:

```
tableQuery = new TableQuery<Entry>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(PartitionKey, QueryComparisons.Equal??,  "CA92.*"));
```

Query Results #2: "CA92122, CA92092".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe so.  Azure Table Storage does not support any operations except equal, greater than, or less than.  Everything else has to be interpreted on the client side.

So you could download of all of the table in memory via ToList and then perform queries as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Service side wants to do simple queries. Supported comparison operators within $filter clause:

Equal, GreaterThan, GreaterThanOrEqual, LessThan, LessThanOrEqual, NotEqual. You can look at the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179423.aspx) to learn more.

Please see the details about querying at [Querying Tables and Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894031.aspx)